# assign inserted_at field in ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I need to test expiration and for that, I need to assign `inserted_at`  field, however when I do:

```
insert_registration(Map.put(attrs, :inserted_at, Ecto.DateTime.cast("2016-03-11 00:00:00")))
```

`inserted_at` field is always overwritten to the current time.

Comment: Check out `Repo.update_all` and similar functions that dont set the timestamps, you could probably use one of those.

Comment: @JustMichael It actually works, I forgot that you need to add :inserted_at in changeset

Comment: @almeynman could you mark your question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you cast `:inserted_at` in your `changeset`

So, if you had something like this:

```
def changeset(account, attrs) do
  account
  |> cast(attrs, [:name, :balance])
  |> validate_required([:name, :balance])
  |> unique_constraint(:name)
end
```

You'd need to change it to:

```
def changeset(account, attrs) do
  account
  |> cast(attrs, [:name, :balance, :inserted_at])
  |> validate_required([:name, :balance])
  |> unique_constraint(:name)
end
```

Assuming you had something like this in your context for Create and Update:

```
def create_account(attrs \\ %{}) do
  %Account{}
   |> Account.changeset(attrs)
   |> Repo.insert()
end

def update_account(%Account{} = account, attrs) do
  account
  |> Account.changeset(attrs)
  |> Repo.update()
end
```

You could then do the following to create:

```
attrs
  |> Map.put(:inserted_at, DateTime.new!(~D[2016-05-24], ~T[13:26:08.003], "Etc/UTC"))
  |> create_account()
```

or the following to update:

```
update_account(account, %{ inserted_at: DateTime.new!(~D[2016-05-24], ~T[13:26:08.003], "Etc/UTC")})
```